# Display Related Nodes by Taxonomy Terms in Block

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

There are numerous articles on how to display related nodes from taxonomy. In all these articles, it states to set contextual filter: Has Taxonomy Term & select option: Taxonomy Term ID from URL.

In my case, I do not have any taxonomy term in the node URL

I want to display nodes which have common terms when the term is NOT in the URL.

I have tried the approach in many articles that require the option: Taxonomy Term ID from URL & select "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks" and further to select the Vocabulary.

I have tried this approach, however, it does not show any related content, possibly as I do not have any terms in the URL?

Please advice.

Comment: where do you want to try this? in node page?

Comment: Yes, in the node display page

Comment: do you have any custom node--your-contenttype.tpl.php , or page--your-contentype.tpl.php for your content type?

Comment: Yes, I have custom content types.

Comment: I mean custom  template for page and node of your content type

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. I am not a developer. I have my own custom node display using Display Suite & blocks.

Comment: it's strange, maybe it need some debugging

Comment: Could you let me know what I should check to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it by using the following method:

Under Advanced
→ Contextual Filter: "Vocabulary Name"
→ Taxonomy Term ID from URL
→ Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks
→ Select Limit terms by vocabulary
→ Select the appropriate Vocabulary
→ Under "Multiple-value handling" Select the appropriate option as per your requirement (either "Filter to items that share all terms" OR "Filter to items that share any term".
That's it. It worked for me.